# wxPython providing a fake-file translation

Tags: internationalization, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to have a base64 encode a .mo file and use it as the translation file for wxPython. Since it will be located in a .py file.

---

I have a wxPython project that is getting compiled a couple different ways. Icons are no trouble because they are packed in a .py file and base64. Translations in .mo files are a pain in the butt. Is it possible to do this same cheat for the translations? Include them not in a correct .mo file, but just dump the translation in base64, or gzipped base64?

`wx.FileTranslationLoader()` seems to be the only `wx.TranslationLoader()` that exists. It says I can replace that translation loader and use my own. https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Translations.html#wx.Translations.SetLoader However to do that I need to return an msgCatalog which isn't apparently an object type that I can find anywhere.

This seems like a solid method of faking this so builders that pack all my .py will be set for their translation files but it doesn't seem easily doable but maybe there's an easy hack I'm missing. Maybe ducktype the MsgCatalog but I dunno what methods it needs to have. And I don't actually want to read the .mo myself, just give it a bytestream like object. In theory I could write the mo a locale directory but usually the internal fileystems of various installs are fake so I'd end up writing some weird files to disk. I suppose I could do that in the temp directory but that seems extra hacky.

Comment: Lost in translation! ;)  So what do you actually want to do?

Comment: edited to make it a sort of thesis.

Comment: `In theory I could write the mo a locale directory`, `wx.Locale` is provided with the function `AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix` to allow flexibility for this very reason.

Comment: @Tatarize, the only problem is - what is the purpose of doing it this way?

Comment: Yeah, but packaging a mo py file is hacky enough, turning around and writing them to disk seems worse. I would want a fake directory thing, or to just inject those files more directly so they wouldn't have to be hacked into different compiles in different ways. --- I did solve this another way with a bunch of debugging but I am still curious if base64 mo files stored in pys is even possible still. I never found a plausible method of doing this though.